# When to Dispose?

Tags: c#, .net, idisposable, using-statement

I'm getting confused about all this talk about IDispose and "using" Statements.  I wonder if someone can tell me if I need to use either a "using" Statement or some sort of implementation of IDispose in the following test example...

```
public class Main()
{
    MyFile myFile = new MyFile("c:\subdir\subdir2\testFile.txt");
    Console.Writeline("File Name: " + myFile.FileName() + "File Size: " + myFile.FileSize());
}

public class MyFile
{
    private FileInfo _fInfo;

    public MyFile(string fullFilePath)
    {
        _fInfo = new FileInfo(fullFilePath);
    }

    public string FileName()
    {
        return _fInfo.Name;
    }

    public long FileSize()
    {
        return _fInfo.Length;
    }

}
```

Comment: First of all, in C#.NET, you can never be sure that you have disposed any object. GC does that for you. You can though tell few things in Destructor but still it won't deallocate memory at your will.

Secondly, using statement is cleaner way than creating your code and implementing IDisposable, or creating Disposable methods.
As the scope of using statement reaches end, all the variables defined and initialized inside are killed.

Comment: @AnubhavSaini: this is false. GC does not dispose for you, and you can always be sure you have disposed if you call Dispose.

Comment: GC collects. Disposing disposes. Calling Dispose method will sure that you disposed. When it gets disposed, no body knows. Still runtime destroyes objects. In most cases, use Using statement and try to write exception safe Disposing functions. @JohnSaunders thanks.

Comment: You're _still_ wrong. Objects get disposed _immediately_ when you call `Dispose`. You are confusing GC with disposal.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Proper use of the IDisposable interface](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/538060/proper-use-of-the-idisposable-interface)

Answer (score 22):

No, your example doesn't use any resources which need disposing (it doesn't touch anything which implements `IDisposable`, or have any direct handles to unmanaged resources) so you don't need to implement `IDisposable`.

Now if you changed your class to *open* the file, and maintain a `FileStream` field referring to the open file handle, *then* it would make sense to implement `IDisposable` to close the stream.

Comment: While you're here, could you explain the part about the similarities between `using()` and the dispose methods? I remember another question where Lippert said something about there being very little difference, but I can't remember what exactly.

Comment: @Walkerneo: A `using` statement is equivalent to a `try`/`finally` block, which disposes in the `finally`.

Answer (score 7):

No, in the code provided I don't see any resource used that have to be disposed. So the answer is *no*, do not use in *this code* it.

Answer (score 6):

In your example there is nothing to dispose, so you have no need to do that.
If you want to read/write in file you can use Streamreader/Streamwriter for that and in that way you will need to dispose that objects after using them.

```
using(StreamReader sreader=new StreamReader())
{
//your code
}
```

So in this case using statement will help you to **don't think** about manually disposing/closing your object/

Comment: What if I added a line of code like the following?              string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(dirPath);

Comment: No need to dispose again. You don't create object that needed to be disposed like streamreader in my example :)

Answer (score 4):

In your code there is no need for any `Dispose` / `using` - for a definitive guide on `IDisposable` see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/538238/847363).

Comment: That link is the best explanation of using the IDisposable interface!